# Where's my query?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, android-app

On searching in the app, and then going through to a question clears the search query when you return back from the question. This is pretty frustrating when the search query happens to be long.

Version 0.1.68

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I broke this a month ago, my bad. Fixed in version 0.1.70 coming out later tonight.